# Mixing java.util.date and a java.sql.Time in Java

Tags: java

I want to construct a date based in a java.util.date and a java.sql.Time, so I code this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,time.getHours());
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,     time.getMinutes());
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,     time.getSeconds());

cal.getTime();
```

It works but ime.getHours(), time.getMinutes(), time.getSeconds() appears as deprecated, how can we make it with a no deprecated method ????

Comment: `java.sql.Time` has date as well so you could just need `cal.setTime(time.getTime())`, assuming your date is just date

Comment: Time is the child class of Date . You can directly use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of what you're doing, I think this is what you want:

```
Calendar mergedCal = Calendar.getInstance();
mergedCal.setTime(date);
Calendar sqlCal = Calendar.getInstance();
sqlCal.setTime(time.getTime());
mergedCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sqlCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
mergedCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, sqlCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
mergedCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, sqlCal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
mergedCal.getTime();
```

At the end of this computation, `mergedCal` will use the date from `date` and the time-of-day from `time`.